# Creating 'structured' missing data in a data table in R

Tags: r, missing-data, genetics

I am doing research in a lab with a mentor who has developed a model that analyzes genetic data, which utilizes an ANOVA. I have simulated a dataset that I want to use in evaluating our model's ability to handle varying levels of missing data.

Our dataset consists of 15 species, with 4 individuals each, which we represent by naming the columns 'A'(x4) 'B'(x4)...etc. Each row represents a gene.

[image]

I'm trying to come up with a code that removes 1% of the data randomly, but such that each species has at least 2 individuals with valid data, because otherwise our model will just quit out (since it's ANOVA-based).

I realize this makes the 'randomly' missing data not so random, but we're trying different methods. It's important that the missing data is otherwise randomized. I'm hoping someone could help me with setting this up?

Comment: You could randomly choose 2 individuals from each group and "protect" them from your 1% random removal. For example move them into a separate `data.frame`. It's hard to give a coding advice without knowing what you already tried.

Comment: You could write a function (say `is.valid`) which checks if a dataset is valid (ie such that each species has at least 2 individuals with valid data) and then run another with a xhile loop which randomly remove data until the dataset is valid (`is.valid` returns `TRUE`). It's named rejection sampling and it's random given the validity specified in `is.valid`.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin Yes, I thought about that but it needs to be a random 2 individuals for each gene. I want it to be as randomized as possible. So that means not every gene has to have missing data, not every species has to missing data consistently across all genes, and that it's statistically likely for each individual to have one missing data in at least one gene. So I can't protect two individuals, because that wouldn't make it as random as it could be.

Comment: @MrSnake That sounds like a good option. My only concern is that couldn't the while loop remove data in more than 2 individuals in a species, which would cause the function to stop before it reaches 1% missing data?

Comment: You can check after each datum you remove (with another checking function ? by storing species name ?) but I think it will be longer.

Comment: Hmm going to have to think on that one. I've only been coding in R for a little over a year so I'm by no means an expert, so I'll try to do some digging on how to do something like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I try to do a toy example that maybe can help

```
is_valid_df<-function(df,col,val){
  all(table(df[col])>val)
}


filter_function<-function(df,perc,col,val){
  n=dim(df)[1]
  filter<-sample(1:n,n*perc)

  if(is_valid_df(df[-filter,],col,val)){
    return(df[-filter,])
  }else{
    filter_function(df,perc,col,val)
    cat("resampling\n")
  }
}




set.seed(20)
a<-(filter_function(iris,0.1,"Species",44))
```